# 3 DOF Robot's initial position and motion error using inverse kinematic block in Simulink

Tags: inverse-kinematics, matlab

I am attempting to control a 3-DOF manipulator by providing XYZ waypoints using a signal builder in conjunction with the inverse kinematics block. The robot model has been imported from SolidWorks.

The SolidWorks model appears as follows:

[image: SolidWorks model]

Where the X, Y, and Z coordinates for the end effector are -0.06 m, -0.26 m, and 0.32 m, respectively.

The Simulink model is attached below:

[image: Simulink model]

I have also attempted to run a simulation without the IK block by providing some inputs to joints q1, q2, and q3 to test the simulation model using slider blocks. By setting the joint values as `q1 = -90`, `q2 = -90`, and `q3 = 0`, I was able to achieve the same pose in MATLAB. The gravity is set as `g=[0 -9.80665 0]`.

However, I'm unsure why I need to provide `q1 = -90` to obtain the default pose for joint-1 (as in SolidWorks) in MATLAB. Normally, the robotic arm should be in a vertical pose following gravity.

When simulating the model  using the inverse kinematic block, the pose of the robot changes. The end effector moves to the negative z coordinate (as shown in the attached figure) of the world frame rather than following the positive z-value. It appears to be deviating from the desired trajectory for the z coordinate (z = 0.32 at t = 0). However, the motion of the end effector in other coordinates is correct.

Mechanical Explorer view in MATLAB

[image: Mechanical Explorer view in MATLAB]

Unfortunately, I was unable to find a solution to make the simulation work correctly for this 3 DOF model.